# Is it possible to show only badge for Firebase push notification, without alert in IOS (Swift or Obj-C)?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase to send remote push notification for an iOS app. Now I need to show only badge in app icon without alert when app is not running. 
Is it possible to implement something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Request `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` permission only when you set permissions in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Remove `.alert`

```
func requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the notification setting options to `.badge` only when you request notifications authorization from user:

```
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge], completionHandler: { [weak self] success, error in
       guard success else {
            guard error == nil else {
                 print("Error occured while requesting push notification permission. In \(#function)")
                 print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                 return
            }
            print("User has denied permission to send push notifications")
            return
    }
    print("User has granted permission to send push notifications")
}
```